# Init GnuPG python, keys aren't imported

Tags: python, gnupg, pgp

I'm trying to init gpg like so:

```
BIN = C:/cygwin64/bin/gpg.exe
HOME = C:/cygwin64/home/Administrator/.gnupg    
gpg = gnupg.GPG(binary=BIN, homedir=HOME)
```

My key rings are located in `C:/cygwin64/home/Administrator/.gnupg` but whenever I use the `list_keys` commands:

```
public_keys = gpg.list_keys()
private_keys = gpg.list_keys(True)
print ('public keys:')
print(public_keys)
print ('private keys:')
print(private_keys)
```

it outputs me empty empty arrays.

So I tried to specify specific paths for rings this way:

```
 gpg = gnupg.GPG(binary=BIN, homedir=HOME, ignore_homedir_permissions=True,
                    keyring='C:/cygwin64/home/Administrator/.gnupg/secring.gpg',
                    secring='C:/cygwin64/home/Administrator/.gnupg/pubring.gpg')
```

same error.

Here are the errors I get whenever I try to decrypt a file:

```
stderr:  gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir `C:/cygwin64/home/Administrator/.gnupg'
gpg: invalid key resource URL `C:/cygwin64/home/Administrator/.gnupg/pubring.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource `(null)': general error
gpg: invalid key resource URL `C:/cygwin64/home/Administrator/.gnupg/secring.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource `(null)': general error
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
[GNUPG:] NODATA 1
[GNUPG:] NODATA 2
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it work when calling gpg directly? These errors come straight from gpg, so Python might not be at fault here.

Comment: It works when calling gpg directly. The python package doesn't recognize my key rings and does nothing when I try to import keys. So it surely comes from the package. I'll try to reinstall it.